# Entities need to be fetched twice with double join in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, join, doctrine-orm, proxy

I use the following code to load an entity with two subsequent joins:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->leftJoin('p.entityAtoentityB', 'ab')
    ->leftJoin('ab.entityB', 'b')
    ->select('a, ab, b')
    ->where('a.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', (int) $id);

$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```

If I check the generated query in Symfony's profiler and run it myself, all of the entities of type B appear in the results.

However, if I try to access the data of those entities of type B, only the first one in the results will not require an additional query, while all the others will appear as (empty) proxy objects until I need to display some of their data, and then Doctrine will run an additional query (based on their primary key) to load them, while they were already loaded in the first query, as shown in the results.

So, in that example, if an object of type A is linked to two objects of type B via the table AB, and the above code has been run, this loop will no generate a query in the first iteration, but it will in the second one, requesting the object of type B using its primary key.

```
foreach ($A->getAB() as $AB) {
    $AB->getB();
}
```

How can I get Doctrine to remember that it's actually loaded the data for all objects of type B and that there's no need for a second query?

NB: getResult() didn't change anything

Comment: why is there "pao" alias in ">leftJoin('pao.entityB', 'b')"?

Comment: should be "ab", now fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following (line 4 change). You shouldn't pass single string to "select" method with comma separated aliases. Pass multiple string parameters instead.

```
1 $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
2    ->leftJoin('p.entityAtoentityB', 'ab')
3    ->leftJoin('ab.entityB', 'b')
4    ->select('a', 'ab', 'b')
5    ->where('a.id = :id')
6    ->setParameter('id', (int) $id);
7
8 $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```